# How to prevent Mongoose from rehashing the user passwords after modifying a user?

Tags: mongoose, schema

Many tutorials out there, tell to use bycrypt within your userSchema page. Once you save a new user, it goes with the encrypted passwords. Great. 
Yet, I figured, that when I edit the user with something, it also rehashes the password, making impossible to log in. Could you please suggest me a solution? Thank you.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const eventSchema = require('./eventSchema');

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: String,
  eventList: [{ 
    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
    ref: "event"
  }],
  administrator: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

// On Save Hook, encrypt password
// Before saving a model, run this function
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // get access to the user model
  const user = this;

  // generate a salt then run callback
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    // hash (encrypt) our password using the salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }

      // overwrite plain text password with encrypted password
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) { return callback(err); }

    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};
// Create the model class
const ModelClass = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

// Export the model
module.exports = ModelClass;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can check whether the password was modified or not - using [isModified](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified).

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const user = this;
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you mean upvoting, unfortunately, I can't yet. I'm lacking enough reputation. I'm sorry. :(

Comment: Thanks, lifesaver!